# How to correctly tag table border with XSL:FO and Apache FOP

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm creating accessible documents using XSL:FO and Apache FOP. To confirm the accessibility, the [PDF Accesibility Checker 3 (PAC3)](http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html) should be used. Unfortunately the checker complains about every single table cell border, because it is an *untagged path object*. So show can I correctly add those tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You'll have to file a bug report with FOP about it.

The borders should be tagged as 'Artifact', but you don't have a separate FO for them, so the FOP technique of using `role="artifact"` (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/accessibility.html#customTags) isn't available to you.  It has to be fixed inside FOP.

FWIW, AH Formatter used to have the same problem.  Also, PAC3 isn't without bugs of its own, though your problem probably isn't a false negative from PAC3.  For example, you will find that it double-counts some errors in its summary, and it perpetually complains about footnotes (but footnote tagging changes in PDF 2.0).  It also can't handle the 'Ruby' tag.  But I digress.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tony!

Answer (score 2):

Resurrecting this question for futurelings:

The pdf-ua-mode option in current FOP turns on excellent tagging without artifacts, and metadata (including the elusive pdfuaid)

fop.xconf:

```
<pdf-ua-mode>PDF/UA-1</pdf-ua-mode>
```

or in a jsp:

```
userAgent.getRendererOptions().put("pdf-ua-mode", "PDF/UA-1");
```